# Javascript regex split for special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yeXWv/

Here I want to split the characters which starts with `[*` or `[*#` and ends with `*]`. The current regular expression split the string which starts with `[*#` but not `[*`. I have tried the following patterns,

`/(\[\*\#*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\*\])/g`

`/(\[\*\#{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+\*\])/g`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to allow for spaces, which was the real problem -- not the missing # character.

```
/(\[\*\#?[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+\*\])/g
```

That will preserve the `[*...*]` strings in the output array. To omit them, remove the parentheses:

```
/\[\*\#?[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+\*\]/g
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/zU576/

Answer (score 4):

Try making the hash character optional:

```
/(\[\*\#?[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+\*\])/g
```

Edit: added missing white space :-)